# How to organize multilingual URLs in ASP.Net Core Razor Pages?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor

**`ASP.NET Core 2.2.0`**

I'm looking for language-based urls in ASP.NET Core. Found a lot of examples online for .NET Core MVC, but can't get it working in Razor Pages.

What I want to achieve is:

- domain.com/informatie -> link to the 'information' page in default language (Dutch for me)
- domain.com/en/information -> link to same the same page in English

Therefor I need 2 features:

1. Recognize the language in the url, or set default language when language-tag is not provided
2. Translate the names of my Pagemodels

I will write a custom method for translating the content.

### Best fitting example

I found 2 examples that do almost the same I want, but they are using MVC:

- [ASP.NET Core: Simple localization and language based URL-s](https://gunnarpeipman.com/aspnet/aspnet-core-simple-localization/)
- [Localized routing using ASP.NET Core MVC 2](https://saaratrix.blogspot.com/2017/12/localized-routing-aspnet-core-mvc-2.html)

The second one looks great, I tried to rewrite it for Razor Pages, but got stuck on the `LocalizationController.cs` (since I'm not using a controller, but a Pagemodel) `CultureActionLinkTagHelper.cs` (I use the asp-page attribute).

Is there anybody who has fixed this in Razor Pages and who would like to share the code? Or anybody who can help me through?

Answer (score 2):

You need to build your application considering globalization/localization.

Here is the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/localization?view=aspnetcore-2.2) from Microsoft.

You may find this tutorial for [Developing Multicultural Web Application](http://www.ziyad.info/en/articles/10-Developing_Multicultural_Web_Application) helpful, it is for DotNetCore 2.1 Razor Pages, but it is valid for 2.2 as well.

Additionally, her is a [sample project for localizing razor pages](https://github.com/LazZiya/MyTrips) in GitHub

Comment: Checked the tutorial and it helps me a lot. But the last missing link for me is how to translate the Pagemodels (the page-name in the url). Is that possible too?

Comment: do you want to have something like `<a href="/en/register/">Register</a>` for English and `<a href="/es/registro/">Registro</a>` for Spanish as an example? if so, I don't prefer to do that, it will add a complicated logic to the routing and it is not really necessary. Localizing only the display text will be enough.

Comment: Yes that is what I want. We have an international company selling products around the whole world, even to people who don't speak or read English. I really want it so that everyone can understand our url's. In this example [link](https://saaratrix.blogspot.com/2017/12/localized-routing-aspnet-core-mvc-2.html) is a pretty simple logic for it, but it is written for MVC and not Razor.

Comment: @CribAd I have been looking to do this in MVC and am so surprised this doesn't seem to be a common thing - I am with you that for our non-english customers it is nice to give them URLS they can understand. after all the drive for MVC was to 'make URL's hackable'...

I know you were looking for Razor Pages but I am so happy you found me something I can attempt in MVC!

Comment: @KrishanPatel you're welcome! Indeed the 2 linked examples are great for MVC!